# For $|a|=24$ and $|b|=10$, find the possibilities for $|⟨a⟩∩⟨b⟩|$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $a$ and $b$ belong to a group. If $|a|=24$ and $|b|=10$, find the possibilities for $|⟨a⟩∩⟨b⟩|$

I know that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$,then $H∩K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

But I'm stuck as to how to use this here to find the answer.

Comment: Not only is $H\cap K$ a subgroup of $G$, but it is also a subgroup of $H$ and of $K$. What does this imply for its order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle$ is a subgroup of both $\langle a \rangle$ and  $\langle b \rangle$, then $|\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle| \mid |a|$ and $|\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle| \mid  |b|$. Therefore, by definition $|\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle| \mid (|a|,|b|)$ where $(|a|,|b|)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of $|a|$ and $|b|$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Did you forget to put the equals sign in between?

Comment: But the answer is given as 1 and 2..how can that be?

Comment: @PiGamma: No, I did it on purpose and I was right to do so. :) In fact, if $a$ and $b$ do not commute with each other, you will get surprised, I think.

Comment: yeah..its clear to me now..thanks so much!